# Getting all log events while passing optional argument

Tags: python, boto3

I am using [boto3 api](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_log_events) to get all the log events in cloud watch.

The following is my code

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("logs")

LOG_GROUP_NAME = "/foo/bar/foo-jobs/foo"
instance_id= "i-somefooid"


log_events = []
response = client.get_log_events(logGroupName=LOG_GROUP_NAME, logStreamName=instance_id, startFromHead=True)
log_events.extend(response["events"])
next_token = response["nextForwardToken"]
while True:
    response = client.get_log_events(logGroupName=LOG_GROUP_NAME, logStreamName=instance_id, nextToken=next_token)
    log_events.extend(response["events"])
    if next_token == response["nextForwardToken"]:
        break
    next_token = response["nextForwardToken"]

print(log_events)
```

Using this I am able to print all the log events for a specified instance id but i am not happy that i have to call `.get_log_events` twice. The reason is because when i make the first call i don't have a `nextToken`. I only have it after the initial call. Is there a way to simplify this so that i only make the `get_log_events` call once inside the while True loop.

I would love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: What you want is the paginator, which handles the nextToken logic for you: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#paginators

Comment: Can you show me how to use this? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import boto3

log_client = boto3.client('logs')

params = {
    'logGroupName': "/foo/bar/foo-jobs/foo",
    'logStreamName': "i-somefooid"
}

log_events = []

while params.get('nextToken') != '':
    response = log_client.get_log_events(**params)
    log_events.extend(response['events'])
    next_token = response.get('nextToken')
    params['nextToken'] = next_token if next_token else ''
```

Comment: Note: this work with boto circa 2021 and if you are checking the latest version of the docs , you will find a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above no longer works in 2023 (and probably hasn't worked since 2022, based on Ralph's comment). Based on [the boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs/client/get_log_events.html), it seems like the API has been changed so that the response contains `nextForwardToken` and not `nextToken`, but the API still needs `nextToken`. So the code above can be adapted as follows:

```
import boto3

log_client = boto3.client('logs')

params = {
    "logGroupName": "/foo/bar/foo-jobs/foo",
    "logStreamName": "i-somefooid",
    "startFromHead": True,  # this is important
}

log_events = []

while True:
    response = log_client.get_log_events(**params)
    log_events.extend(response["events"])
    next_token = response.get("nextForwardToken")
    if next_token == params.get("nextToken"):
        break
    params['nextToken'] = next_token
```